# Invalid Binary when upload to app store

Tags: xcode, upload, app-store, app-store-connect, application-loader

When I upload my ipa to the AppStore using Application Loader, the ipa status change to Invalid Binary and I get this email from Apple...

[image]

The problem is in my info.plist there is a key of `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` which could be the possible problem !

Comment: So what is your question; do you currently have an `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` in your `Info.plist`?

Comment: Yes I have `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` in my `Info.plist` file but I still have the error message from Apple

Comment: what is usage description you have written to NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription  tag?

Comment: I write in the Info.plist (Base) `<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Touch &amp; Delivery app asks to access photos Library</string>`, and in the Info.plist(Arabic) `<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>تطبيق لمسة يريد الوصول لألبوم الصور</string>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, my problem was there is more than one plist file in the project, and the xCode is using a plist file that does not contain the required key.

So I removed all versions of duplicated files, and keep just single one.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer,

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses photos</string>
```

you need to specify product name in description like above.

Comment: $(PRODUCT_NAME) is not really required, because I can write anything in this field to explain why my app using this permission, the problem was multi plist files exits in my project and the xCode uses a version that does not contain the required key

Answer (score 0):

Add new row in info plist then paste this `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`.

Hope it helps.